# My php update query does not work

Tags: php, sql-update

```
    if(isset($_POST["trimite"]))
    {
        $nume=$_POST["nume"] ;
        $prenume=$_POST["prenume"] ;
        $bust=$_POST["bust"] ;
        $talie=$_POST["talie"] ;
        $sold=$_POST["sold"] ;
        $par=$_POST["par"] ;
        $img1=$_POST["imagine1"] ;
        $img2=$_POST["imagine2"] ;
        $img3=$_POST["imagine3"] ;
        $idsal=$_POST["id_salariu"];
        $id=$_GET["id"];
        $update_query="UPDATE `model` 
                                    SET `nume` = '".$nume."'
                                    AND `prenume` = '$prenume'
                                    AND `bust` = $bust
                                    AND `talie` = $talie
                                    AND `sold` = $sold
                                    AND `culoare_par` = '$par'
                                        WHERE 
                                            `id_model`=$id";

        $update_query1="UPDATE `poze` 
                                SET `cale_poza` = '$img1'
                                    AND `cale_poza1` = '$img2'
                                    AND `cale_poza2` = '$img3'
                                        WHERE 
                                            `id_model`=$id";
        $update_query2="UPDATE `salariu` 
                                SET `id_salariu` =$idsal
                                        WHERE 
                                            `id_model`=$id";
                                            echo 'MySQL server version: %s\n'. mysqli_get_server_info($connection);
        $update=mysqli_query($connection, $update_query);
        $update1=mysqli_query($connection, $update_query1);
        $update2=mysqli_query($connection, $update_query2);
        if ($update) {
            echo "Record updated successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($connection);
        }}
```

Hello!
       I have these columns in phpMyAdmin database: `nume(varchar), prenume(varchar), bust(int), talie(int),sold(int),par(varchar),cale_poza(varchar),cale_poza1(varchar),cale_poza2(varchar),id_salariu(int).`

When I want to run those queries on phpMyAdmin, they work, but when I run them in php they do not work. For instance, when I want to update the "nume" field from "Prey" to "Prey1", the "nume" field will recive 0. All the fields recieve the same value when I try to update.
Thank you, in advance!

Comment: echo `$update_query1` and paste the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your sql query and try

```
$update_query="UPDATE `model` 
                                    SET `nume` = '".$nume."'
                                    ,`prenume` = '$prenume'
                                    ,`bust` = $bust
                                    ,`talie` = $talie
                                    ,`sold` = $sold
                                    ,`culoare_par` = '$par'
                                        WHERE 
                                            `id_model`=$id";

 $update_query1="UPDATE `poze` 
                                    SET `cale_poza` = '$img1'
                                        ,`cale_poza1` = '$img2'
                                        ,`cale_poza2` = '$img3'
                                            WHERE 
                                                `id_model`=$id";
```

Comment: It works, thank you. Now I have another problem: fields "cale_poza", "cale_poza1" and "cale_poza2" are supposed to be the file path from some photos locally stored. Not, when I update, from ex"C:\\wamp\www\BD\Imagini\aastha_p2.jpg" it updates me with "C:wampwwwBDImaginiaastha_p2.jpg", which is not right, and my src link from <img> tag does not recognize the image..